# Most efficient data processing strategy, potential double and missing values

Tags: r, data-processing

There are a lot of (inefficient) ideas I have about processing this data, but was suggested to me on another question to directly ask you all in another Q.

Basically, I have a lot of data that was taken by multiple users, with an ID number for the sample, and two weight variables (pre and post processing). Because the data was not processed sequentially by ID, and the data was collected at very different times for pre- and post-processing, it would be difficult (and probably increase data entry error likelihood) for the user to locate the ID and pre- column to input the post.

So instead the dataframe looks something like this:

```
#example data creation
id = c(rep(1:4,2),5:8)
pre = c(rep(10,4),rep(NA,4),rep(100,4))
post = c(rep(NA,4),rep(10,4),rep(100,4))
df = cbind(id,pre,post)

print(df)
      id pre post
 [1,]  1  10   NA
 [2,]  2  10   NA
 [3,]  3  10   NA
 [4,]  4  10   NA
 [5,]  1  NA   10
 [6,]  2  NA   10
 [7,]  3  NA   10
 [8,]  4  NA   10
 [9,]  5 100  100
[10,]  6 100  100
[11,]  7 100  100
[12,]  8 100  100
```

I asked another question on [how to merge the data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70852700/merging-data-in-r-within-the-same-dataframe/70852808?noredirect=1#comment125256739_70852808), so I feel alright about that. I want to know what the best method is to sweep the dataframe for user error before I merge the columns.

Specifically, I am looking for if one ID has a pre but not a post (or vise versa), or if there is a double entry for any of the values. I would ideally just like to pump out all strange data (doubles, missing) IDs into a new dataframe so then I can go investigate and see what the problem is.

For example, if my data frame has this:

```
   id pre post
1   1  10   NA
2   1  10   NA
3   2  10   NA
4   3  10   NA
6   2  NA   10
7   3  NA   10
8   4  NA   10
9   5 100  100
10  6 100  100
```

How do I get it to recognize that id #1 has been entered twice, and that ids 1 and 4 are missing a post and pre entry? All I need it to do is detect those anomalies and spit them out into a dataframe!
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure the following is all the question asks for.

```
na <- rowSums(is.na(df[, -1])) > 0
df[duplicated(df[,1]) | na, ]
#     id pre post
#[1,]  1  10   NA
#[2,]  2  10   NA
#[3,]  3  10   NA
#[4,]  4  10   NA
#[5,]  1  NA   10
#[6,]  2  NA   10
#[7,]  3  NA   10
#[8,]  4  NA   10
```

Comment: Ahhh not quite? I edited my question above to try to clarify what I would be looking for. Does that help? Thank you!

Comment: @lmbradley See now after the edit. I'm still not sure if you want an OR (`|`) or an AND (`&`)  in the 2nd code line. But it did help.